# Delete single value from Cloud Firestore Array

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[image: FirestoreScreenshot]

I am trying to delete the single `"m80KEXuYelOGutSLtQelQkIDj9H2"` value from within my `"players"` array in Cloud Firestore.

Logs show that String findTeam is `CoolTeam1` and String userId is `m80KEXuYelOGutSLtQelQkIDj9H2`

My code is:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("teams").document(findTeam);
docRef.update({"players":FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId)});
```

I'm getting "Unexpected token" in Android Studio for the `{` and the `})` in the above.

Any ideas would be much appreciated?

I have also tried using dot notation as per below, this runs but does not delete the value:

```
db.collection("teams").document(findTeam).update("players." + userId, FieldValue.delete());
```

I have also tried using a Map update, this also runs and shows "Deleting player successful" in the Log. But the player is not removed in Firestore.

````
Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put(userId, FieldValue.delete());

doc.update(updates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

       if (task.isSuccessful()){
       Log.i(TAG, "Deleting player successful");
       }
       else{
       Log.i(TAG, "Deleting player NOT successful");
       }
      }
});```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your first code sample with the curly braces is trying to use the JavaScript syntax for updating a document rather than the Java Android syntax.  That's not going to work at all, obviously.

[FieldValue.delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#delete()) is going to work at all for you either, since that's used for deleting an entire document field, not modifying an array.  You will want to use [FieldValue.arrayRemove()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#arrayRemove(java.lang.Object...)) instead, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).  Be sure to use the Java Android syntax.

Try this instead:

```
db.collection("teams").document(findTeam).update("players",
    FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out eventually...

Import the class:

```
import static com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove;
```

Then use:

```
db.collection("teams").document(findTeam).update("players", arrayRemove(userId));
```